# Vuetify data table component - Truncate text in cell using CSS

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

In the following example, is there any way to use CSS to truncate the text in the cell (rather than have it wrap around or overflow)? Ideally, the CSS should look something like this:

```css
.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But as you can see below, this just causes the cell to consume all the space:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <style>
.truncate {
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 200px; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
      <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
        <span class="truncate">{{ item.name}}</span>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    headers: [
      { text: 'Name', value: 'name', width: "75%" },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', width: "25%" },
    ],
    items: [
      { name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159, },
      { name: 'Ice cream sandwich with a really, really, really long name that keeps going on and on and on forever so there is no space left', calories: 237, },
      { name: 'Eclair', calories: 262, },
    ], }
})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is possible to achieve the desired effect by specifying a fixed width in pixels, but I would like the table and its columns to be responsive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you apply the truncating to the td instead, and applying the magic hack `max-width: 1px` you will get your desired result.

In the example below, in order to apply the class to the `td` you have to use the item slot and create the row yourself.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <style>
    .truncate {
      max-width: 1px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
          <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
            <tr>
              <td class="truncate">{{ item.name}}</td>
              <td>{{ item.calories}}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: {
        headers: [{
            text: 'Name',
            value: 'name',
            width: "75%"
          },
          {
            text: 'Calories',
            value: 'calories',
            width: "25%"
          },
        ],
        items: [{
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich with a really, really, really long name that keeps going on and on and on forever so there is no space left',
            calories: 237,
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
          },
        ],
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Impressive! I have seen the `max-width: 1px` hack, but I wasn't sure how to apply it in this context. Is it reliable? I am guessing there is no way around it?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I remembered the hack from an old project of mine.

Comment: Fair enough! I will leave the question open for a bit longer to see if anybody knows a way to do it without the "hack". Still, this is the best way to get the desired behavior that I have seen so far...

Comment: Thats alright. Would be happy to see alternatives myself!

Comment: Well, I have found the `max-width: 1px ` hack to work well in practice, and there doesn't really seem to be a nicer way to achieve the desired behavior, so I am going to accept this answer.

Comment: Awesome solution and works like a charm! Have been trying all kind of other options but none seem to work!

Comment: Something to do with "table-layout: fixed;"  should be able to achieve the same thing: https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by setting the css max-with value to a responsive vw value:

```
    .truncate {
       max-width: 50vw;
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow: hidden;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you just change the SPAN to a DIV and uncomment the width in the css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <style>
.truncate {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items">
      <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
        <div class="truncate">{{ item.name}}</div>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    headers: [
      { text: 'Name', value: 'name', width: "75%" },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', width: "25%" },
    ],
    items: [
      { name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159, },
      { name: 'Ice cream sandwich with a really, really, really long name that keeps going on and on and on forever so there is no space left', calories: 237, },
      { name: 'Eclair', calories: 262, },
    ], }
})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```